# AttributeError: 'Logger' object has no attribute 'FileHandler'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to add FileHandler to logger object in my script:

```
FOO_LOGGER = logging.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME)

# create the logging file handler
fh = FOO_LOGGER.FileHandler('foo.log')
```

and I am getting this error:

> AttributeError: 'Logger' object has no attribute 'FileHandler'

I am using python version Python 2.7.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has no object like that.

Try:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')

# create file handler which logs even debug messages
fh = logging.FileHandler('spam.log')

logger.addHandler(fh)
```

More can be found here: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
import logging

#Create and configure logger 
logging.basicConfig(filename="foo.log", 
                format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', 
                filemode='w')

FOO_LOGGER = logging.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME)

FOO_LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

FOO_LOGGER.info("Your Message!")
```

Answer (score 1):

To write to console and a file:

```
console = logging.StreamHandler()
file_handler = logging.FileHandler("D:\Shared\wbc_customer.log.txt", "w")
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(asctime)-15s: %(name)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
    handlers = [file_handler, console]
)
```